# Save to the local computer a text file with the local sotrage's list of items

Tags: angular

I want to get my list of items to a text file and let the user download it to his computer, the list is at my local storage,
Is there anyway to do it ?

```
private setLocalStoragePersons(persons: Person[]): void {
    localStorage.setItem('persons', JSON.stringify({ persons : persons}));
}}

getList(){
    const localStorageItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persons'));
    return localStorageItem == null ? [] : localStorageItem.persons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the great [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) library.

Install:

`npm install file-saver --save`

Import `saveAs` function in your controller:

```js
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`
```

Perform downloading the file:

```js
const blob: Blob = new Blob(['YOUR TEXT HERE'], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
saveAs(blob, 'FILE_NAME.txt');
```